# Pymongo: Handling SQL Injection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using Pymongo to do database operations and it seems that the command I'm using is being flagged as having SQL Injection vulnerability.

Here is my original query:

```
e = client[db_name]['request'].find_one_and_update(filter={'_id': ObjectId(request_id)},
                                                   update={'$unset': reset_data},
                                                   return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

I'm changing it and use mongosanitizer to sanitize the query, so it becomes

```
from mongosanitizer.sanitizer import sanitize
...

find_query = {'_id': ObjectId(request_id)}
sanitize(find_query)
e = client[db_name]['request'].find_one_and_update(filter=find_query,
                                                   update={'$unset': reset_data},
                                                   return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

This seems to work fine. But there is problem if the query is a list, so for example:

```
find_query = {"_id": {"$in": req_ids}}
```

where `req_ids` is an array. So basically the `sanitize` function removes everything that has `$`. But in some cases, it's actually necessary. So how do I sanitize such query?

Comment: Since MongoDB is a NoSQL database I'd like to see how exactly it is *"flagged as having SQL Injection vulnerability"*.

Comment: @KlausD. I'm using Checkmarx and the code is being highlighted by the tool as having "Second_Order_SQL_Injection"

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it. Either you permit $ operator (with the risk of NoSQL injection) or not. Of course you could do advantage checks with regular expressions.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit in normal SQL, we have prepared statements/parameterized query, so even we have array, it can still properly be sanitized. Wondering whether is there such a thing for NoSQL/MongoDB. Otherwise it sounds like NoSQL is riskier than SQL counterpart

Comment: There are no prepared statements in MongoDB. However, when you like to pass an array into a SQL prepared statement, they you also need special functions, i.e. you cannot simply pass an array when a scalar value is expected. In this point there is no difference between NoSQL and relational SQL databases.